# Unable to derive module descriptor for legacy signed JAR

Tags: module, java-11, java-platform-module-system

I'm trying to update a software system to JDK-11 using modules, and everything was going just fine right up until I slammed head-on into the aforementioned issue.

I have a legacy signed JAR that I need to incorporate for interaction with legacy systems. There's no way to update the JAR and no way to get a new version. The JAR *must* be signed in order to be usable (the whole "trusted code" deal and whatnot).  The problem is that the JAR contains classes in the unnamed (root) package. Yeah. Stupid. Bad practice. Blablabla. It's still there, and I still need to use it.

I've not found any documentation or answers anywhere that would remotely suggest that what I need is possible. In fact, the opposite is true: everyone is adamant that in the "new"(ish) module system, no class may reside in the unnamed package.

Needless to say I'm unable to both modify the contents of the JAR, or get at the sources to render a new one - that's without even considering the issue of the signature...

That said: I refuse to believe the folks at Oracle would leave such a glaring oversight with regards to legacy code.  As we all know, a lot of the time we have no choice but to use it for legitimate reasons, and we can't do anything to fix/update/refactor/etc...  I would have hoped there was a mechanism added to the module system to support this, albeit for extreme cases only, etc...etc...

Disclaimer: I do fully understand why this isn't meant to be supported. What I'm having a hard time with is the lack of a workaround...

Thanks!

I've already tried:

- creating a facade module that transitively adds the offending module (obviously no dice, same problem)
- unpacking-and-repacking the module while temporarily disabling signature validation in a test env (fails because the class is apparently referenced within many other, properly-organized classes)
- finding an updated module (no luck here, either)
- beheading a chicken and roasting it over a pentagram while invoking the aid of ancient pagan gods (tasty, but didn't fix it)
- curling up in a ball under my desk and weeping until execution succeeds (that's where I'm typing this from)...

Comment: Sorry to say, but I don't believe it's possible to have classes in the default package and use Jigsaw modules at the same time. Note you don't necessarily have to use modules when using Java 11. Everything can remain on the classpath and should work as it did in pre-module Java.

Comment: The workaround is to leave the JAR file on the class path but it means that any modules with references to the classes in this JAR file will need to be compiled and run with `--add-reads <module>=ALL-UNNAMED`. JEP 261 has a section entitled "Increasing readability" that explains the --add-reads option.